# Find String in file, replace a part of it under linux

Tags: xml, awk, sed

I have a string like this in a file with the name `/etc/rmm/config.xml`:

```xml
<Service Name="ssh" DisplayName="SSH Daemon" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSVINIT" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"/>
```

I want to change `Enabled="true"` to `Enabled="false"`. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Well... without further information: `sed -i 's/Enabled="true"/Enabled="false"/' /etc/rmm/config.xml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most direct way to achieve this is using `xmlstarlet`. **In general, it is unsafe to use text processing like `awk` or `sed` to handle XML files**, so `xmlstarlet` (or a full-fledged XSLT-1.0 processor like `xsltproc`) is the way to go.

It is easy like that:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u /Service/@Enabled -v "false" input.xml
```

With an input file like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Service Name="ssh" DisplayName="SSH Daemon" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSVINIT" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"/>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Service Name="ssh" DisplayName="SSH Daemon" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSVINIT" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="false"/>
```

Adjust the XPath after `-u` according to your needs. For example, to change all `Service` element's `Enabled` attributes from "true" to "false", you could use

```
xmlstarlet ed -u //Service/@Enabled -v "false" input.xml
```